# Why does border-radius look like crap on the iPad?

Tags: css, ipad, safari

See the white jaggies on the corners? Is this a problem with my CSS or is this actually what it is supposed to render like?

Here's my CSS:

```
border: 1px solid       rgba(0,0,0,.33) /*{d-bup-border}*/;
background:             #fff /*{d-bup-background-color}*/;
font-weight: bold;
color:                  #223d74 /*{d-bup-color}*/;
text-shadow: none;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#fff /*{d-bup-background-end}*/)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff /*{d-bup-background-start}*/, #fff /*{d-bup-background-end}*/); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff /*{d-bup-background-start}*/, #fff /*{d-bup-background-end}*/); /* FF3.6 */
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff /*{d-bup-background-start}*/, #fff /*{d-bup-background-end}*/); /* IE10 */
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff /*{d-bup-background-start}*/, #fff /*{d-bup-background-end}*/); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #fff /*{d-bup-background-start}*/, #fff /*{d-bup-background-end}*/);
```

[image]

Comment: I *think* I can see what you're talking about...I don't think I would have noticed though.

Comment: Does it look just as bad on desktop Safari? It should.

Comment: @BoltClock - In Safari it looks crisp, I'm only seeing it on the iPad.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this problem on safari and tried finding a resolution that resolved it for me many of months ago. Sadly I can't find the original post.

Although I think the answer your looking for that may resolve your issue is [background-clip](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-clip)

```
-moz-background-clip: padding;     /* Firefox 3.6 */
-webkit-background-clip: padding;  /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
background-clip: padding-box;      /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */
```

[image: Background Clip]

Taken from [CSS Tricks - Transparent Borders with background-clip](https://web.archive.org/web/20111210012551/http://css-tricks.com:80/7423-transparent-borders-with-background-clip/)